# Event is not firing on button located in a table in an iframe (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, iframe, addeventlistener

I have to show a spinner upon clicking an add button in a HTML form waiting for the Ajax to load the content in a select box. The select box is located in an iframe. I have set up a simplified reproduction of what I am trying to achieve in jsfiddle. There are 2 tables, one for Research Project and one for 
Primary research group. The tables contain an add icon. I want to fire a console.log upon clicking the add button of just the Research Project.

I have to use the name of the parent container in the selector as there are no other non-textual identifiers in the user interface. I want to just plain JavaScript, but if jQuery or some other framework offers a solution, then I will go for that.

```
var formFrame = document.getElementById('form_iframe');
formFrame.src = "/catorarn/tabLe/24/show/";
var formFrameDoc = formFrame.contentDocument;

formFrame.onload = function() {
  //click event on add button
  var btn = getElementByXpath("//i[contains(@class,'fa fa-plus-circle') and ../../td/span[text()='Research project']]", formFrame);
  console.log('showSpinner === btn is ' + btn);

  addEvent(btn, 'click', function(e){
    console.log('inside event listener');
    e.stopPropagation();
   });
 };

function getElementByXpath(path, iframe) {
  console.log('iframe is ' + iframe );
  var doc = iframe.contentDocument;
  return doc.evaluate(path, doc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

function addEvent(elem, evnt, funct){
   if (elem.attachEvent){
     console.log('addEvent === attachEvent');
     return elem.attachEvent('on' + evnt, funct);
   } else {
     console.log('addEvent === addEventListener == elem is ' + elem );
     return elem.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
   }
  }
```

I have created a fiddle reproducing the problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/catorarn/hhz09dec/126/)

The event is not registering on the button at all, when I click Run in jsfiddle.
Why is the event not registered?

Comment: I have been told that I should try looping through the DOM using getElementsByClassName and other DOM API. I found a way of doing it differently

Answer (score 0):

```
  var formFrame = document.getElementById('form_iframe');
  formFrame.src = "/catorarn/tabLe/29/show/";

  formFrame.onload = function() {
  var formFrameDoc = formFrame.contentDocument;

  //click event on add button
  var tables = formFrameDoc.getElementsByClassName('iw-formspub-container');
  var children ;

  for (var i = 0 ; i < tables.length; i++ ){
    children = tables[i].getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++ ){
      if( children[j].textContent === 'Research project' ){
         var btn = formFrameDoc.querySelector(".fa.fa-plus-circle");
         btn.addEventListener('click', function(){ console.log('finally'); });
       }   
    }
  }
};
```

The xpath selector that I had to use was going to be ugly and complex, something like

```
//i[contains(@class,'fa-plus-circle') and ../../../../../../../../../../../td/table/tbody/tr/td/span[contains(text(),'Research project')]]
```